# Bash, print 0 in terminal each time a non recognised argument is input

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I have a bash program which extracts marks from a file that looks like this:

```
 Jack ex1=5 ex2=3 quiz1=9 quiz2=10 exam=50
```

I want the code to execute such that when I input into terminal:

```
./program -ex1 -ex2 -ex3
```

Jack does not have an ex3 in his data, so an output of 0 will be returned:

```
Jack 5 3 0
```

how do I code my program to output 0 for each unrecognized argument?

Comment: How are you reading the data from the file? How are you printing the results back out?

Comment: I have found the answer to this but am unable to answer my own question for a few hours, thank you for looking into my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, it isn't that difficult. What you need to do is read each line into a `name` and the remainder into `marks`. (input is read from `stdin`)

Then for each argument given on the command line, check if the first part matches the beginning of any grade in `marks` (the left size of the `=` sign). If it does, then save the `grade` (right side of the `=` sign) and set the `found` flag to `1`.

After checking all marks against the first argument, if the `found` flag is `1`, output the `grade`, otherwise output `0`. Repeat for all command line arguments. (and then for all students in file) Let me know if you have questions:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i found=0                  # initialize variables
declare -i grade=0

while read -r name marks; do        # read each line into name & marks
    printf "%s" "$name"             # print student name
    for i in "$@"; do               # for each command line argument
        found=0                     # reset found (flag) 0
        for j in $marks; do         # for each set of marks check for match
            [ $i = -${j%=*} ] && { found=1; grade=${j#*=}; } # if match save grade
        done
        [ $found -eq 1 ] && printf " %d" $grade || printf " 0" # print grade or 0
    done
    printf "\n"                     # print newline
done

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash marks_check.sh -ex1 -ex2 -ex3 < dat/marks.txt
Jack 5 3 0
```